# Matrix representations of maps between vector spaces - convention

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Semi Riemannian Geometry by Newman, in which the matrix representation of a linear map w.r.t. bases $H$ of $V$ and $F$ of $W$ between vector spaces $A:V\to W$ is defined by $$A(h_j)=\sum_ia_{ij}f_i$$
where $h_j\in H$ and $f_i\in F$ are basis vectors in $V$ and $W$ respectively. $[a_{ij}]$ is the matrix representation.

Now explicitly this hasn't been extended to dual vector spaces and such, for which the index convention is slightly different. So I just wanted to be extra sure if my understanding is correct (as follows):

Let $T:V^*\to W^*$, and $\Theta$ and $\Psi$ be bases of $V^*$ and $W^*$ respectively. If $T(\theta^i)=\sum_jt_{ij}\psi^j$, then $[T]_{\Theta}^{\Psi}$ would actually be the transpose of $[t_{ij}]$, since $$T(\theta^i)=\sum_jt_{ij}\psi^j=\sum_j(t^T)_{ji}\psi^j$$
so that the RHS above is the same as RHS of the first equation I wrote in this question.

In another application, I have this result for the flat map $F:V\to V^*$ (where $V$ is equipped with the bilinear function $b$ whose representation in basis $H$ is $[b_{ij}]$):
$$F(h_j)=\sum_ib_{ji}\theta^i$$
Again to find the matrix representation of $F$ w.r.t. $H$ and $\Theta$ (basis dual to $H$), I sort of need to force the RHS into the same form as the RHS of the first equation in the question:
$$F(h_j)=\sum_ib_{ji}\theta^i=\sum_i(b^T)_{ij}\theta^i$$
and so $[F]_H^{\Theta}=[b]^T$

My question is: is the above rule of thumb / convention correct? To find the matrix representation of any map between vector spaces, I need to force the summation term in the same form as the first equation, and then use the sum coefficients as matrix elements? **In words, if we consider the target basis expansion of the transformed version of the $j$-th source basis vector/covector, then the coefficients are given by the $j$-th column of the matrix representation.**

Sorry if it's a basic question but I want to be very sure in my concepts.